# [Swift]When trying to use my login button I need to press it twice after communicating with the mySQL Server

Tags: php, ios, json, authentication, swift3

I am creating an application that uses a login and register page. After a user registers their account it is in my mySQL database. So when I go to test the login, I will press login, then nothing happens, however I am receiving a message from my php saying "success" but the application will not segue until I click on the Login button again. I thought that maybe my if statement was in the wrong location, but I can't figure out where to move it because my task.resume is locked to where it is, and the if statement needs to execute with a button press. I feel like this will be an easy problem to fix, but for the life of me I cannot figure it out. All help is appreciated, this is my loginViewController.swift file.(I removed my POST website on purpose)

```
import UIKit

extension UIViewController {
func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
}



class loginViewController: UIViewController {


struct globalVariable {
    static var response = String()

}

@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!



@IBAction func loginButtonTap(_ sender: Any) {

    do {
        let request = try NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"


        //Getting the values from the text fields and creating the post parameter
        let postString = "email=\(emailTextField.text!)&password=\(passwordTextField.text!)"


        //Adding the parameters to request body
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        //Creating a task to send the post request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
            data, response, error in


            if error != nil{
                print("error is=\(error)")
                return;
            }

            print("response = \(response)")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(responseString)")


            globalVariable.response = responseString as! String

        }
        task.resume()

            if globalVariable.response.range(of: "true") != nil{

                var loginSwitch = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController

                var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginSwitch

        }


    }









}















override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the response from webservice inside the completion handler, as it stands, its trying to handle the response from the webservice before the webservice has returned.

```
    //Creating a task to send the post request
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil{
            print("error is=\(error)")
            return;
        }

        print("response = \(response)")

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("responseString = \(responseString)")

        if responseString.range(of: "true") != nil{
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                var loginSwitch = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabBarController") as! UITabBarController
                var appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
                appDelegate.window?.rootViewController = loginSwitch
            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
```

Comment: Ive tried that before, it gives me an error because task.resume needs to be called before I do the if statement I guess. It shoots the error libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)  and takes me to the 0 __pthread_kill and says Thread 10: signal SIGABRT

Comment: try my updated answer, i forgot the completion handler is running on a background thread, so you cant do UI modifications directly in the completion handler, you need to put that logic back onto the main thread.